# How to make my page centered in IE

Tags: html, css

Hi there, I designed a forum but the main problem that I have is the page would not centered. 
I set the main element to `margin: 0 auto;` it doesn't helpful and of course setting to `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` none of them worked.

My html code is here:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="main"><!--Begin Main-->
                <div class="container"><!--Begin container-->
                    <div id="header"><!--Begin Header-->

                            <ul id="menu" >
                            <li><img src="images/mark.png" /><a href="#">Login</a></li>                         
                                <li> <img src="images/mark.png"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul >
                                    <li>  <img src="images/mark.png"/><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><img src="images/mark.png" /><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <div id="logo"><!--Begin Logo-->
                            <h1>BLOOMSKIN</h1>
                        </div><!--End logo-->
                        <div id="tagline"><!--Begin Tagline-->

                            <h2>Your Forum</h2>
                        <div/><!--end Tagline-->
                        </div><!-- End header-->
                        <div id="position"><!--Begin Position-->
                            <h5 style="float:left;"><a href="#">View unanswered post </a></h5>

                            <h5>&nbsp;|<a href="#"> View active topics</a></h5>
                            <h5 id="date_time">it is a current time Thus jun 09,2011    11:10am</h5>
                        </div><!--end Position-->
                    </div><!--End Header-->
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div id="content"><!--Begin Content-->
                        <div id="hold_white_content">   
                            <div style="padding-bottom:15px;"></div>

                            <div id="content_of_category">
                                    <h3 id="category">Category</h3>

                                    <div class="Form_Header">
                                        <h4 id="Furom_Format">Forum</h4>
                                        <h5 id="Set_status">Status</h5>
                                        <h5 id="Set_status">Last Post Info</h5>
                                    </div>
                                   <div  style="clear:both"></div>

                                <div id="title_exam">
                                <h2>Title Example</h2>
                                    <h3>5 Topic</h3>
                                    <img src="images/Rec_Another.png" style="float:left;"/>
                                    <h4>Another title example</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <div id="desc">
                                    <h4><i>This is a description of post</i></h4>
                                    <h3>25 Replies</h3>
                                    <h5><i>By Hussein39 At Thus,2011,jun <br> 20 17:48 AM</i></h5><hr style="text-shadow:#999" />
                                </div>
                                <div id="title_exam">
                                <h2>Title Example</h2>
                                    <h3>5 Topic</h3>
                                    <img src="images/Rec_Another.png" style="float:left;"/>
                                    <h4>Another title example</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <div id="desc">
                                    <h4><i>This is a description of post</i></h4>
                                    <h3>25 Replies</h3>
                                    <h5><i>By Hussein39 At Thus,2011,jun <br> 20 17:48 AM</i></h5><hr style="text-shadow:#999" />
                                </div>
                                <div id="title_exam">
                                <h2>Title Example</h2>
                                    <h3>5 Topic</h3>
                                    <img src="images/Rec_Another.png" style="float:left;"/>
                                    <h4>Another title example</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <div id="desc">
                                    <h4><i>This is a description of post</i></h4>
                                    <h3>25 Replies</h3>
                                    <h5><i>By Hussein39 At Thus,2011,jun <br> 20 17:48 AM</i></h5><hr style="text-shadow:#999" />
                                </div>
                                                            <div id="title_exam">
                                <h2>Title Example</h2>
                                    <h3>5 Topic</h3>
                                    <img src="images/Rec_Another.png" style="float:left;"/>
                                    <h4>Another title example</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <div id="desc">
                                    <h4><i>This is a description of post</i></h4>
                                    <h3>25 Replies</h3>



                                    <h5><i>By Hussein39 At Thus,2011,jun <br> 20 17:48 AM</i></h5>
                                </div>
                                            <div style="padding-bottom:20px;"></div>                
                                </div>
                             <div style="padding-bottom:15px;"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div id="new_topic_button">
                        </div>

                    </div><!--End Content-->
                    <div id="button">
                        <a href="#">New Topic</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer"><!-- Begin Footer-->
                        <div id="login"><!--Begin login-->
                            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
                            <hr class="line">
                            <ul id="login_info">
                            <li>UserName:</li>
                            <li><input type="text"  name="username" class="textbox"/></li>
                            <li>Password:</li>
                            <li><input type="text" name="password" class="textbox"/></li>
                            <li> | Log me on automatically each visit</li>
                            <li> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  /></li>
                            <li> <input type="button"  value="Log in" id="loginbutton"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--End login section-->
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        <div id="status"><!-- Begin Who is online section-->
                            <h3>Who is Online</h3>
                            <hr class="line" />
                            <p>In total there are  2 users online: 4 registered 1 hidden and 5 guests (base on users active over the past 6 minutes)
                            Most users ever online was 12 on sat 24th june,2010 6:59 pm</p>

                            <div id="reg_user">Register users: No Registered users</div>
                            <div id="legend">
                                Legend:  <a id="admin" href="#">Administrator</a>
                                        <a id="general" href="#">, Global moderators</a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--End Status Who is online section-->
                    </div><!--End footer Section-->



                </div><!--End container-->
            </div><!--End  main-->
        </body>
    </html>
```

and my css code is here:

```
        *{ margin:0;
        padding:0;}
        #main
        {
            width:800px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
        body{background-color:#000; color:#FFF;}
        #header
        {   
            background:url(images/header.png)  no-repeat;

        }

        #header li
        {
            list-style-type:none;
            float:left;
            padding-left:20px;
            padding-top:20px;
            padding-bottom:50px;

        }

        #header li a
        { text-decoration:none; font-family:"MS Serif", "New York", serif
        font-size:18px; font-weight:700; color:#FFF; margin-top:10px; padding-left:5px;}
        #header li img
        { 
            height:25px; 
            width:25px;  
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        #menu
        {
            float:left; 
            padding-right:250px;
        }
        #logo h1
        {
            font-family:"Gill Sans Ultra Bold Condensed";
            font-size:43px;
            font-weight:bold;

        }
        #tagline h2
        {
            font-family:"Monotype Corsiva"; font-size:36px;
            padding-bottom:30px;    
        }

        #position h5
        {   
            float:left;
            padding-bottom:30px;
        }
        #position h5 a
        {
            text-decoration:none; 
            color:#FFF; 
        }
        #date_time
        { padding-left:150px;}
        #hold_white_content
        {
            -moz-border-radius:10px;
            background-color:#FFF;
            width:670px;
            height:auto;
            color:#000;
        }
        #content_of_category
        {
            background:url(images/cat_header.png) repeat-x  #e0e0e0;
            width:630px;
            border:1px  solid #000;
            margin:auto;
            height:auto;
            border-bottom-right-radius:15px 15px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 15px;
        }
        #Set_status
        {
             float:left; 
             padding-left:10px; 
             padding-top:0px; 

        }
        /*#content_of_category h4{float:left;padding-top:20px; padding-left:10px; font-size:12px;}*/
        #category{ padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px; }
        #Furom_Format{ float:left; font-size:12px;}

        .Form_Header {padding-top:25px; padding-left:10px;}

        #Set_status{ padding-left:190px;}


        #title_exam
        {padding-top:20px; padding-left:10px;}
        #title_exam h2
        {

            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; color:#77c8df;

            float:left;
        }
        #title_exam h3
        {


            font-size:14px; 
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#000;
            float:left;
            padding-left:130px; padding-right:60px;
        }
        #title_exam h4{color:#58b8e1;}
        #title_exam img{ padding-left:90px;  }
        #desc h4{ float:left; padding-left:10px;  font-size:14px; ; font-weight:100; text-align:center;}
        #desc h3{float:left; font-size:14px; font-weight:700;    padding-left:70px; padding-right:120px;}
        #desc h5{ float:left  font-size:12px; ; font-weight:100;   text-align:center; color:#9a9c9c;}
        #button
        {
            background:url(images/button.png) no-repeat;
            height:46px;
            padding-top:10px;

            margin-top:15px;
            margin-left:15px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        #button a
        {
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family:"Gill Sans Ultra Bold Condensed";
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#f6f6f6;
            padding-left:35px;

        }

        #login ul{list-style-type:none; padding-top:10px; padding-left:5px;}
        #login ul li
        {
             float:left;

        }
        .textbox
        {
            width:100px;
            margin-left:2px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
        #checkbox
        {
            margin-left:2px;
        }
        #loginbutton
        {
            margin-left:10px;
        }
        .line
        {
            border-color:#03F;
            width:650px;
        }
        #status
        {
            padding-top:50px;
            width:650px;    
        }
        #status p{ padding-left:5px; line-height:25px;}
        #reg_user
        {
            padding-top:50px;
        }
        #legend  
        {   padding-top:20px;

        }
        #admin
        {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#F00;
        }
        #general
        {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#0F0;
        }
```

Comment: @Ojaghi if your question was answered you really should come back and accept the one that worked for you. It helps the community a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just do -

```
#main{
      margin:0px auto;
}
```

It works with IE also.

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct doctype and by using the following CSS you can do that.

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

"Width" is must to center align the whole content in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed width, you can do it like this:

```
#main {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nXMsC/

The left margin must be half of the total width of your element. If the element is 800px wide and has, say, 16px padding, the half width may be 416px depending on your box model.

Answer (score -1):

Hi now define your **body** `text-align:center` this is only **ie**

and `#main` define `text-align:left;`

as like this

```
body{
text-align:center; // only  for ie
}

    #main{
    text-align:left;
margin:0 auto; // for latest browsers
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this one & i hope it will work for you also in all browsers

```
#main {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `<center>` tag also but for this you should include this in all pages.

```
<body>
<center>

Your Page Content

</center>
</body>
```